# Measuring memory usage in R

Tags: r, memory

Consider two vectors:

```
a <- 1
b <- 1:100
```

Why is the result of this line of code:

```
sum(sapply(ls(),function(x){utils::object.size(get(x))}))
#488 (bytes)
```

different from this line of code:

```
utils::object.size(ls())
#152 bytes
```

Comment: Because `ls()` is a character vector containing the names of the objects in the global environment, while `get(x)` is the actual object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first version is giving you the correct result:

```
object.size(a)  ## 32 Bytes
object.size(b)  ## 424 Bytes
sum(sapply(ls(),function(x){utils::object.size(get(x))}))  ## 456 Bytes
```

While the second, is doing essentially:

```
object.size(c("a", "b"))  ## 96 Bytes
```